# Boost::any and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, boost-any

I am using `boost::any` to store pointers and was wondering if there was
a way to extract a polymorphic data type.

Here is a simple example of what ideally I'd like to do, but currently doesn't work.

```
struct A {};

struct B : A {};

int main() {

    boost::any a;
    a = new B();
    boost::any_cast< A* >(a);
}
```

This fails because a is storing a B*, and I'm trying to extract an A*.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other way is to store an `A*` in the `boost::any` and then `dynamic_cast` the output. Something like:

```
int main() {
    boost::any a = (A*)new A;
    boost::any b = (A*)new B;
    A *anObj = boost::any_cast<A*>(a);
    B *anotherObj = dynamic_cast<B*>(anObj); // <- this is NULL

    anObj = boost::any_cast<A*>(b);
    anotherObj = dynamic_cast<B*>(anObj); // <- this one works!

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Boost.DynamicAny is a vairant on Boost.Any which provides more flexible dynamic casting of the underlying type. Whereas retreiving a value from Boost.Any requires that you know the exact type stored within the Any, Boost.DynamicAny allows you to dynamically cast to either a base or derived class of the held type.

https://github.com/bytemaster/Boost.DynamicAny

Comment: I've just started using this: it works exactly as I require... and no heap allocation/new'ing needed, which will make the API that I'm writing very clean from a user's point of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I think the only way to do it is this:

```
static_cast<A*>(boost::any_cast<B*>(a))
```