# boost::any violates Liskov substitution principle

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, type-erasure, boost-any

I've found that it's impossible to extract a reference to a base type from [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html) which is holding a derived type:

```
boost::any holder = Derived();
const Base& base_ref = boost::any_cast<const Base&>(holder);
```

throws a `boost::bad_any_cast` exception.

It seems like this is a violation of [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and not very convenient. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: C++ is a multiparadigm language, meaning **it's not all about Object Oriented Programming**. Having said that, `boost::any` is clearly not meant to be used in a polymorphic way, so the LSP does not apply.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it "violates" it - `boost::any` isn't designed for what you're using it.

It is specifically designed to work with value types (see the docs, to which you already posted a link).

You must any_cast to exactly the type the any variable holds; under the hood, it's checking the typeid. Clearly, `const Base&` isn't a match for `Derived` in this case.

`std::shared_ptr< Base >` provides /almost/ what you seem to want. Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088689/boostany-and-polymorphism?rq=1) for some more info.

Comment: Of course I would use a shared pointer if I had a common base class for all types that could be passed around, but apparently it's not my case.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution principle still applies, in the sense that the code compiles and works. The design of `boost::any` is such that it raises an exception (and you can recover from it if you want).

An alternative design of `boost::any` may choose to do something different. For a more fine grained version of boost::any you can look at Boost.TypeErasure. (Although probably `std::unique_ptr` will do the job you want.)